# How do I call a method from another class while passing context?

Tags: java, android

I have this code and I want to access this from another class:

```
 public void nomorA(int num){   
        try {
            am = ctx.getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = am.openFd("nom.wav");
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
            player.setLooping(false);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How do I call this method from `Main Activity` and pass its context to the called method?

Comment: Create a object of the class and call this method `<objectName>.nomor_urut(int number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add Context as second parameter and make static function

```
public class Utility{

    public static void nomorA(int num,Context ctx){

    }
}
```

Call function :

```
Utility. nomorA(1,ClassName.this);
```